# iOS app works in simulator but doesn't even open on phone, iOS Distribution Certificate Expires issue?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, ios-simulator

I have an app that was deployed on the app store in June 2019 and it hasn't been changed since then and has been working fine.  Right now though, when you try to open the app, it just flickers and crashes (no error), but when I open it in simulator to debug it works just fine.

Can someone suggest some things I can research to get an idea of what could be causing this issue? I have gotten a new mac since the app was deployed to the app store and I just searched and found an email from apple with the subject "Action Needed: iOS Distribution Certificate Expires in 30 Days" on 3/21 which may be related.  I have to confess I am very confused by the whole certificate process and when I saw that email I thought it only affected future apps not ones that were already deployed and on user's phones.

It is a simple app that crowd sources a photo collection and displays it in a slide show (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/big-day-of/id1460532495).  I haven't made any updates or changes because the app was working and the fact that it works in simulator rules out any server side issues, so I have to assume it is something with the swift/app store connect/certificates situation?

Comment: I installed the app and it works fine. Is the app on your device from the store?  Apps installed from the store don't expire. Apps from Xcode do.

Comment: Thanks... I found out that my phone replaced a dev version with the one installed on my app... which expired as normally does for testing.  User error!  You don't by any chance know anything about the certificate process or know a good tutorial?